# Как передать AJAX'ом данные из DatePicker в контроллер yii2

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

DatePicker создается следующим кодом:

```
$form->field($model, 'cdate')->widget(DatePicker::className(), ['clientOptions' =>
        ['dateFormat' => 'd MM yy'],
        'options' => ['class' => 'col-md-2',
            'onChange' => '$("#btn_submit").prop(\'disabled\',\'disabled\')',
        ],
    ])
    ->label(FALSE)
    ->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Я плейсхолдер', 'value' => $today]);
```

Он создается в представлении которое рендерит функция actionIndex в контроллере. В этом action есть две переменные, сейчас они выглядят вот так

```
$formatter = \Yii::$app->formatter;
//сегодняшний день
$dateDay = $formatter->asDate('now', 'dd');
//текущий месяц
$dateMonth = $formatter->asDate('now', 'MM');
```

Как я могу данные с DatePicker'a без перезагрузки страницы передать в эти переменные?

UPD: я все починил, сделал в представлении вот так:

```
'onSelect' => new \yii\web\JsExpression('function (date, instance) {
 $.ajax({
 type: \'POST\',
 url: \'index\',
 data: \'date=\' + date,
 success: function (result) {
       console.log(\'success\' + \' \' + date)
   },
});
```

В инструментах разработчика приходит следующее: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при этом

```
$userDate = Yii::$app->request->post();
var_dump($userDate);
```

всегда выводит `array(0) { }` даже если я делаю `var_dump()` в представлении, однако функция `success` срабатываем и в консоль выводится правильное время. Как можно получить данные из запроса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант: можно задать в `options` данного виджета какой нибудь `id` или лучше `data` параметр.

Пример:

```
'options' => [
   'class' => 'col-md-2',
   'data-role' => 'datepicker-widget',
   'onChange' => '$("#btn_submit").prop(\'disabled\',\'disabled\')',
],
```

И затем создать обработчик на js который будет отлавливать изменение значения в виджете и отправлять аякс запрос.

Пример:

```
$(document).on('change', '[data-role=datepicker-widget]', function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: '/site/ajax', //путь до экшена к которому пойдёт обращение по ajax-у
      ...
   });
});
```

Comment: а как его потом в контроллере принять?

Comment: Допустим так: `Yii::$app->request->get()` или `Yii::$app->request->post()` в зависимости от того каким методом передадите параметры в ajax

Comment: я в своем action который рендерит это представление делал var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post()) и мне сразу при перезагрузке выдал array(0) это неправильно было?

Comment: если перезагружали просто по F5 то да. вы ведь никакие post-параметры при этом не передаёте. отправьте аяксом данные на какой нибудь другой контроллер и внутри делайте `var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post());` затем в панели разработчика на вкладке "Network" смотрите что выдаст вам вар_дамп

Comment: Разобрался) и последний вопрос) Я могу как то указать чтобы мне post возвращал не массив а строку?

Comment: Потому что стандартный DataType ни в каком формате не работает( данные перестают отправляются при указании этого свойства

Comment: если мы говорим об ajax запросе и его приём ответа то лучше всего получать json в ответ и дальше с ним работать. передавайте из контроллера данные в формате json и получайте его внутри `$.ajax({success: function(data) {}});` где data - объект json

Comment: Я почти все исправил и дополнил вопрос, не могли бы вы дать ответ на вопрос после "UPD"

Answer (score 1):

Не могу комментировать, так как нет 50 репутации. Вам нужно смотреть на var_dump() в панели разработчика. 
Скажите, пожалуйста, где Вы прописываете данный код:

`$userDate = Yii::$app->request->post();
var_dump($userDate);`

Вы должны прописать его в action, к которому обращается ajax, и тогда ответ с сервера можно будет наблюдать в панели разработчика. И в этом ответе вы увидите результат выполнения функции `var_dump()`

Comment: `$userDate = Yii::$app->request->post();
var_dump($userDate);` я прописываю в actionIndex который рендерит представление Index (`url: Index` это оно и есть) и он выдает array {0} всегда, даже после отправки данных с виджета

Comment: Скиньте Ваш скайп, будет проще Вам все объяснить

Comment: Вы очень любезны, правда) но это мой рабочий проект и все файлы рабочие файлы находятся на рабочем компьютере, спасибо большое Вам за предложение)

Comment: Я покажу на своем примере, покажу свой экран